# GNAT GPL 2017 gnatcoll.xref disappeared?

Tags: ada, gnat

I'm trying to upgrade to GNAT GPL 2017 (from 2016). I'm running on Windows 8.1.

One application uses gnatcoll.xref.

In 2016, that's found in:

gnat/include/gnatcoll/gnatcoll_sqlite.static/gnatcoll-xref.ads

However, the file is not found in the 2017 install. Note that the 'gnat-...-bin.exe' installer for 2017 includes gnatcoll, while in 2016 it's a separate install.

The gnatcoll user guide for 2017 (share/doc/gnatcoll/GNATColl.pdf) chapter 25 says gnatcoll.xref should be there (it is used in the example code).

Has anyone else run into this? And is there a fix/workaround?

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it by installing gnatcoll from source, overwriting the binary install. gnatcoll.xref now requires iconv (2016 did not), so I had to install that in mingw32, and convince gnat to use it. Here's a brief summary:

mingw32 packages:

```
     mingw-w64-i686-make
     mingw-w64-i686-iconv
     mingw-w64-i686-pkg-config
     libiconv-devel
```

in a mingw32 shell:

```
export PATH=/d/Apps/GNAT-gpl_2017/bin:$PATH
./configure --build=mingw32 --prefix=/d/Apps/GNAT-gpl_2017 --with-iconv=d:/msys32/mingw32/
```

in a Cygwin shell (mingw32 make screwed up, not sure why):

```
make
make install
```